# Rails Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory when saving an upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm having the following issue with my Rails API.

I am trying to save a file into a temp directory.  My initial assumption was that I should be able to save it into the system `/tmp` directory, because that's what that directory is for.  So I have the following code in my `gallery_images_controller.rb`:

```
    def upload
        # set the upload
        upload = params[:qqfile].original_filename
        # we want to save files in tmp for now
        directory = "/tmp"
        ap(directory)
        # create the full path for where to save the file
        path = File.join(directory, upload)
        ap(path)
        # get the md5 of the file so we can use it as the key in the json response
        md5 = Digest::MD5.file(path).hexdigest
        # save the file
        File.open(path, "w+b") { |f| f.write(params[:qqfile].read) }
        # render the result with the md5 as the key and the filename and full path
        render json: {success: true, upload: {"#{md5}": {filename: upload, full_path: path}}}, status: 200
    end
```

When I send the post request with the file I get the following error:

```
{:error=>true, :message=>"Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/3Form-Museum-of-Science-25.jpg"}
```

I also tried to save the file in the Rails.root tmp folder and get the same error:

```
directory = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"

{:error=>true, :message=>"Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /vagrant/tmp/3Form-Museum-of-Science-25.jpg"}
```

I've also tried the mode as `w+b`and `wb` to no avail.

The documentation for Ruby (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-new) says that the the `w` and `w+` modes should create the file if it doesn't exist. Which is exactly what I want it to do, and it's not.

Also, I have checked the permissions on the folders.  The `/tmp` folder, as you would expect, has 777 and the rails root `/vagrant/tmp` has 755 just like all the other folders in the rails root.

Please help!

---

System Information:

- Dev: Vagrant box running ubuntu 14.04, unicorn and nginx
- Prod: Amazon EC2 running ubuntu 14.04, unicorn and nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just run the

```
File.open(path, "w+b") { |f| f.write(params[:qqfile].read) }
```

before

```
md5 = Digest::MD5.file(path).hexdigest
```

Just swap the two lines so that the file is created before a hex digest is calculated to it

Comment: Thanks, a friend helped me figure this out as well.  I posted my answer and right as I did the page refreshed and I saw yours, so I've accepted yours and the answer!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that makes it here with this same issue here is what I did to fix it.

There were 2 issues that I fixed to resolve this:

1. I changed this line:

   File.open(path, "w+b") { |f| f.write(params[:qqfile].read) }

To this:

```
File.open(path, "w+b") { |f| f.write(path) }
```

2. Moved the line above to be ***above*** the `md5` line

So now my upload function looks like this:

```
def upload
        # set the upload
        upload = params[:qqfile].original_filename
        # we want to save files in tmp for now
        directory = "/tmp"
        # create the full path for where to save the file
        path = File.join(directory, upload)
        # save the file
        File.open(path, "w+b") { |f| f.write(path) }
        # get the md5 of the file so we can use it as the key in the json response
        md5 = Digest::MD5.file(path).hexdigest
        # render the result with the md5 as the key and the filename and full path
        render json: {success: true, upload: {"#{md5}": {filename: upload, full_path: path}}}, status: 200
end
```